# Atalho Localizar e Substituir Visual Studio Code

Tags: editor-de-texto, visual-studio-code

No Visual Studio Code, quando eu pressiono as teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> eu consigo localizar uma determinada string.

Existe algum atalho para o "localizar e substituir" usando este mesmo programa?

*Ex: No Atom ao localizar uma string se pressionar o tab vou para o campo de substituir, gostaria de algo semelhante.*

Comment: Pessoal acabei de encontrar a resposta nesse link: [atalhos] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0zz35x06(v=vs.90).aspx). Basta dar um Ctrl + H

Answer (score 2):

Já encontrei a resposta basta um Ctrl + H. Quem tiver dúvidas semelhantes olhe o link > [atalhos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0zz35x06(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Boa dica! Só complementando, o "Ctrl + H" localiza e substitui no documento atualmente aberto, mas quem quiser localizar e substituir mesmo em documentos fechados mas que pertençam à pasta atualmente aberta no VS Code, só usar "Ctrl + Shift + H" (sem aspas)